# Facebook c# sdk mvc3 canvas issue with CanvasAuthorize

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm creating a mvc3 canvas app using facebook c# sdk

The method name is **create**.

I also do a post and have another **create** method with **[HttpPost] attribute**.

When I add the  **[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions)]** attribute to both the create methods,  and a link from another page calls this create method, **normally the get method should get called but in this case the post method gets called**

But **if I comment the post method** then **it goes to the get method**.

Any ideas how to solve this.

Thanks
Arnab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the canvas authorization posting the access token into the page. The only way around it I've found is to create a different action that deals the post and use that action inside the view as post target. It will look something like this:

```
// /MyController/MyAction
// Post and Get

[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel data)
{
    MyModel modelData = data;

    if(data==null)
    {
        modelData = new MyModel();
    }
    else
    {
        modelData = data;
    }
    return View(modelData);
}

// /MyController/MyActionPost
// POST only

[HttpPost]
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions]
public ActionResult MyActionPost(MyModel data)
{

    if(Model.IsValid)
    {
         //Processing code with a redirect at the end (most likely)
    }
    else
    {
         return View("MyAction", data);
    }
}
```

Then in your MyAction view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionPost", "MyController"))
{
    <!-- Form items go here-->

    <inpuy type="submit" value="Submit" />

    @Html.FacebookSignedRequest()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It was doing a GET before, then suddenly when browse to an action with [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions)] attribute, it's doing a POST instead of a GET.